# How to create filter in Angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding, angularjs-filter

I have this collection of courses:

```
 [{ id: 1, courseId: 2, text: 'John' },
  { id: 2, courseId: 2, text: 'Willi' },
  { id: 3, courseId: 2, text: 'Inga' },
  { id: 4, courseId: 1, text: 'Jerry' },
  { id: 5, courseId: 1, text: 'Michael' },
  { id: 1, courseId: 3, text: 'John' },
  { id: 2, courseId: 3, text: 'Willi' },
  { id: 3, courseId: 4, text: 'Inga' },
  { id: 4, courseId: 5, text: 'Jerry' },
  { id: 5, courseId: 5, text: 'Michael' }]
```

And I have this array of id's:

```
[{"id": 3},{"id": 2},{"id": 1}]
```

I need to filter array of courses by array of id's(i.e to display only text courses that have courseId = 3,2,1 ):

```
ng-repeat="course in courses| customFilter: [{"id": 3},{"id": 2},{"id": 1}]"
```

I need to create custom filter in angularJS that will filter array of courses by array of id's.

Any idea how can I implement customFilter for this purpose?

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter#creating-custom-filters

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create your custom `filter` so that can provide you the filtered values, filter should take array of element to be filter array.

**Markup**

```
ng-repeat="course in courses| customFilter: [{"id": 3},{"id": 2},{"id": 1}]""
```

**Filter**

```
app.filter('customFilter', function(){
  return function(array, filterArray){
     var ids = [];
     angular.forEach(filterArray, function(val, index) {
        ids.push(val.id);
     }
     return array.filter(function(value){
        return ids.indexOf(value.id) !== -1;
     });
  }
})
```

Comment: ,I have this format filter:
customFilter: [{"id": 3},{"id": 2},{"id": 1}]"
Not this: customFilter: [3,2,1]"

Comment: why you need this kind of filter..why dont simplify it??

Comment: because this result I get from the serivce.And I need to keep it in the foramt as abouve

Comment: though I've made changes accordingly..do look at them.

Comment: thanks for the help but seems that there is some errors

Answer (score 0):

I have created a filter in angularJs project.

in my angular app name is angularApp.

```
var app = angular.module('angularApp', []); // This is your main angular app.
```

**Now you want to create a filter for decode url.**

```
app.filter('decodeURL', function() {
    return function(text) {
        if(text) {
            return text.split(' ').join('-').toLowerCase().replace(/[^a-z0-9]+/g, '-');
        }
    }
});
```

**The above code is to create a filter to decode url. And my filter name is 'decodeURL' . we will use decodeURL as a filter in my code**
like if your URL is-

**http://www.example.com/test1 test2 tes3**

then filter make the URL like this-

**http://www.example.com/test1-test2-tes3**

**How to use this filter in the html-**

```
<a ui-sref="{{business.category[0].categoryName.toLowerCase()}}Detail({id:business.id,title:(business.title | decodeURL)})"></a>
```

**// The above is for state routing in angularjs.**

```
<a href="/coupon/{{coupon.id}}/{{coupon.title | decodeURL}}"
                                       class="btn btn-warning show-btnhome show-button-margin">Show</a>
```

**//The above code for URL redirecting.**

[image: Please see in the snapshots]

[image: Please see in the snapshots]

[image: Please see in the snapshots]